# Алгоритм/формула для подбора цвета в RGB по монохромным образцам

Tags: алгоритм, преобразование, цвета, формулы, rgb

В сети интернет много статей о преобразовании цвета в RGB в градации серого. Где утверждается, что составляющие RGB вносят разный вклад в цветовосприятие, поэтому приводится формула преобразования с коэффициентами, если я не ошибаюсь:

`((0.2989*R)+(0.5870*G)+(0.1141*B))`

Меня интересует обратная задача. Например у меня есть цвет зеленого оттенка [image] и пусть ему соответствует (не переводится, а именно соответствует) [image]. Вопрос, как мне, учитывая вышеозначенное соответствие, найти оттенки зеленого для:

| Оттенок серого | Оттенок зеленого |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | ? |
| [image] | ? |
| [image] | ? |

Интересует алгоритм/формула.

Comment: Что такое "оттенки зеленого"? Какие технические характеристики должны быть у цвета, чтобы вы сочли его подходящим вам "оттенком зеленого"?

Comment: А по указанной формуле из `90D12D` получается `ABABAB`, так что в итоге всё совсем непонятно

Comment: Я не могу привести именно строго технические характеристики понятия "оттенок зеленого". Но если описательно - это цвет, в котором визуально больше всего присутствует зеленая составляющая, а стальные оставляющие формируют неосновную раскраску, а формируют отклонения от строго зеленого. Ну это должно быть интуитивно понятно, например "зелено-желтый" - это зеленый цвет с некоторой примесью желтого. И наоборот "желто-зеленый" - это желтый цвет с некоторой примесью зеленого.

Answer (score 0):

Решение подсказали знакомые. Частичное - в сторону осветления. Но меня это устраивает, и вот пример, как получается:

| Оттенок серого | Оттенок зеленого |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

В первой строчке, в левом столбце серый цвет, который нужно заменить зеленым (салатовым), который справа. В строчках ниже серый цвет становится ярче - для него считаем оттенки "опорного" (салатового).
Формула будет следующая для каждой цветовой компоненты отдельно:

`V = 255 - (255 - Color) * (255 - Gray) / (255 - Start)`
, где:

- V - рассчитываемое значение новой цветовой составляющей из RGB
- Color - цветовая составляющая опорного цвета
- Gray - цветовая составляющая рассчитываемого серого цвета
- Start - цветовая составляющая стартового серого цвета

Пример расчета для `#E2E2E2`:

```
R = 255 - (255 - 0x90) * (255 - 0xE2) / (255 - 0xDA) = 0xA8
G = 255 - (255 - 0xD1) * (255 - 0xE2) / (255 - 0xDA) = 0xDB
B = 255 - (255 - 0x2D) * (255 - 0xE2) / (255 - 0xDA) = 0x5A
```

Округления делал 0.5 и меньше - в меньшую сторону, более 0.5 - в большую. Если кто напишет более универсальную формулу/способ, в том числе не только для осветления, но и для затемнения - вэлком. Ну а мой вопрос решен.